# Horizontally Align ULs In Different

Tags: html, css

I have the below code which displays list items horizontally.

However, the horizontal alignment gets broken up between the ULs.  Is it possible to have all of the list items aligned across the ULs?  ie so that item 6 appears below item 2 etc.

```css
div,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  width: 1400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="firstdiv">
    <ul class="firstul">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="seconddiv">
    <ul class="secondul">
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="thirddiv">
    <ul class="thirdul">
      <li>Item 9</li>
      <li>Item 10</li>
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
      <li>Item 13</li>
      <li>Item 14</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You need to brake in different ul's?

Comment: Yes. It's auto generated content I need to work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumming that you need to keep your HTML structure like that, apply `display: inline` to your lists and their div wrappers:

```css
div,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.container div,
.container ul {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="firstdiv">
    <ul class="firstul">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="seconddiv">
    <ul class="secondul">
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="thirddiv">
    <ul class="thirdul">
      <li>Item 9</li>
      <li>Item 10</li>
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
      <li>Item 13</li>
      <li>Item 14</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A future alternative may be to apply `display:grid` to your container and `display: contents` to its descendant `<div>` and `<ul>` elements. Granted, the support for `display: contents` is [limited at the moment](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents).

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, calc(25% - 7.5px));
  grid-gap: 20px 10px;
}

.container div,
.container ul {
  display: contents;
}

.container li {
  list-style: none;
  outline: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="firstdiv">
    <ul class="firstul">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="seconddiv">
    <ul class="secondul">
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="thirddiv">
    <ul class="thirdul">
      <li>Item 9</li>
      <li>Item 10</li>
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
      <li>Item 13</li>
      <li>Item 14</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```